# How to run basic tests on a Jekyll project?

Tags: testing, jekyll

How would you run basic tests at build time for a Jekyll project? For example, run tests on frontmatter variable or the output html? More specific example: count the number of words in a frontmatter variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run basic tests at build time for a Jekyll project, you can use a combination of Jekyll's Liquid templating language and scripting tools. Here's an example of how you can count the number of words in a frontmatter variable using Jekyll

Create a new file in your Jekyll project's root directory called test_word_count.rb (or any other name of your choice).

In this file, you can write a script that extracts the frontmatter variable you want to test and counts the number of words. Here's an example script: `require 'yaml'

## Read the YAML frontmatter from the Jekyll file

frontmatter = YAML.load_file('_posts/your_post.md') # Replace with the path to your Jekyll file

## Extract the frontmatter variable you want to test

variable = frontmatter['your_variable'] # Replace 'your_variable' with the actual variable name

## Count the number of words in the variable

word_count = variable.split.size

## Print the word count

puts "Word count: #{word_count}"
`
Replace '_posts/your_post.md' with the path to the Jekyll file that contains the frontmatter variable you want to test. Replace 'your_variable' with the actual variable name you want to count the words for.

Save the file and exit.

Open your terminal or command prompt, navigate to your Jekyll project's root directory, and run the script using the following command: `ruby test_word_count.rb`

The script will extract the frontmatter variable, count the number of words in it, and display the word count in the terminal.

You can modify this example to suit your specific testing needs, such as testing the output HTML or performing other checks on frontmatter variables. Remember to update the file paths and variable names accordingly.

Note that this approach assumes you have Ruby installed on your system, as Jekyll is built using Ruby.

Comment: Please use codeblocks and better formatting to make your answers a bit more readable

Comment: Thanks, might also want to add about editing the _config.yml file so the test code is not published/served with the rest of the content for the jekyll site.

Comment: Also I think most people will need to add argument to load file: permitted_classes: ['Date']